# Reference resource in CloudFormation template in inline code property of a Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a `CloudFormation` template that has a `Lambda` function resource that is triggered by a CloudWatch event when a new `AMI` is registered. In the Lambda resource block, I pass my inline code in the `Code` property. The function triggers an `SSM` automation document execution if the `AMI` id is the desired id parsed in the return event. For the sake of the question, let's call this resource `My Doc` in the template. So, my question is, in my template how would I reference the Automation Document resource in my inlide code in the `Code` property of the `Lambda` resource? I have pasted a code sample below to help illustrate this.

Resource blocks from template:

```
"MyDoc": {
    {
      "Type" : "AWS::SSM::Document",
      "Properties" : {
        "Content" : JSON object,
        "DocumentType" : Automation,
        "Tags" : [ Resource Tag, ... ]
      }
}

"MyLambdaFunction": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Properties": {
                  "Role": {
                      "Fn::GetAtt": [
                          "SomeRole",
                          "Arn"
                      ]
                  },
                  "Code": {
                      "ZipFile": {
                          "Fn::Join": [
                              "\n",
                              [
                                  "import json",
                                  "import boto3",
                                  "def lambda_handler(event, context):",
                                  "    ssm = boto3.client('ssm')",
                                  "    amiId = event['AMI-ID']",

                                  "    if 'base_ami in amiId:",
                                  "         ssm.start_automation_execution(DocumentName=THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO REFERENCE THE DOCUMENT RESOURCE)",
                                  "    else:",
                                  "        print("Not the base AMI id.")"
                              ]
                          ]
                      }
                  },
                  "Runtime": "python3.6",
                  "Timeout": 300,
                  "Handler": "index.lambda_handler",
                  "MemorySize": 512
              }
          },
          ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, in order for your Lambda to get that document you would first have to pass the document's logical id to the Lambda. You can do that using `!Ref MyDoc` in the [Lambda Environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-environment), and then you can pull that variable inside the function and use [GetDocument API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_GetDocument.html) to get the document.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Although, I believe the `!Ref MyDoc` is `YAML` syntax. `JSON` syntax would be `{ "Ref" : "MyDoc" }`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) intrinsic function instead of Join for this purpose. Or even combination Join and Sub functions - up to you.

So, the result code can look like this:

```
"Code": {
                  "ZipFile": {
                      "Fn::Join": [
                          "\n",
                          [
                              "import json",
                              "import boto3",
                              "def lambda_handler(event, context):",
                              "    ssm = boto3.client('ssm')",
                              "    amiId = event['AMI-ID']",
                              "    if 'base_ami in amiId:",
                              { 
                                "Fn::Sub": [ 
                                    "         ssm.start_automation_execution(DocumentName=${MyDocumentName})", 
                                    { "MyDocumentName": {"Ref" : "MyDoc" }} 
                                ]
                              }
                              "    else:",
                              "        print("Not the base AMI id.")"
                          ]
                      ]
                  }
              }
```

And of course this will only work for inline code, otherwise you should use Lambda Environment Variables, as @Deiv wrote.